# how could one use percentage for the header when the width for the body hasn't been set

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

This is the html:

```
<body>
  <!-- Forked from a template on Tutorialzine: https://tutorialzine.com/2016/06/freebie-landing-page-template-with-flexbox -->
  <header>
    <h2><a href="#">Mountain Travel</a></h2>
    <nav>
      <li class="new"><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="hero">
    <div class="go_crazy"></div>
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/img/main.jpg);" >
    </div>
    <div class="hero-content-area">
      <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
      <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
      <span class="old"><a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a></span>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

This is the CSS:

```
/*Header Styles*/

header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 35px 100px 0;
    animation: 1s fadein 0.5s forwards;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Inside the CSS file, there is no set for the width of the body, but why the developer could use 100% for the header??
I think it means 100% of the width of the parent. So could anyone explain this for me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser automatically sets the width of the `<body>` element equal to the width of the browser window.

Example: If your browser window is 800px wide, you can imagine the browser inserts the following CSS:

```
body {
  width: 800px;
}
```

You can't see that CSS in your own code, but it's there, hidden inside the browser. So you are correct in thinking that setting the `<header>` to 100% width means it should be 100% of the width of the parent, and this is why that works in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel unhappy because the tutorial doesn't tell me this, which makes me very confused and wasted me lots of time

Comment: @renesmith You're welcome! Yeah I understand the frustration. Unfortunately this is the kind of detail that is often left out of tutorials, either by mistake or ignorance. It's possible the author has never even thought about this small detail, or that they've known about it for so long they took it for granted and forgot to mention it. Either way it was a good question to ask, and people on here should be happy to help answer similar questions if you get stuck in the future.

Comment: Does this mean the value is flexible? I mean I could always change the width of the broswer,  and all the width of the elements will change with it?

Comment: That's correct! The browser updates that hidden `width` value anytime you resize it, which will cause all children to update as well, and so on.